# Send an email having an attachment for multiple addresses in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I wrote the below code for sending an email to multiple addresses.... But i am able to send the mail for only first address in the list...could give me exact reason and solution for it. Thanks in advance!!

```
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.application import MIMEApplication
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from smtplib import SMTP
COMMASPACE = ', '

msg = MIMEMultipart()
msg['Subject'] = 'Test attaching mail'
msg['From'] = 'x@x.com'
msg['Reply-to'] = ''
msg['To'] = COMMASPACE.join(['x1@x.com','x2@x.com','x3@x.com'])

# That is what u see if dont have an email reader:
msg.preamble = 'Multipart massage.\n'

# This is the textual part:
part = MIMEText("Hello im sending an email from a python program")
msg.attach(part)

# This is the binary part(The Attachment):
file="../logs_usecase/TestUsecase.log"
part = MIMEApplication(open(file,"rb").read())
part.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment', filename=file)
msg.attach(part)

# Create an instance in SMTP server
smtp = SMTP("smtp.gmail.com:587")
# Start the server:
smtp.starttls()
smtp.ehlo()
smtp.login('x@x.com', "xxxxx")

# Send the email
smtp.sendmail(msg['From'], msg['To'], msg.as_string())
```

Comment: Well, considering that you're running `SMTP` you'd might as well just split the addresses into a loop, `for to in [...]:` and send it manually, because that's what will happen anyway if i'm not mistaken. SMTP doesn't recognize multiple to addresses, the client usually splits it up before sending. Or i've just used really old mail servers when debugging :)

Comment: @Torxed SMTP certainly supports addressing a single message to multiple recipients ([RFC 5321, page 35](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5321#page-35))

Comment: @lanzz Yepp, sorry! Mixed up the ends on the mailserver, incomming e-mails can be adressed by multiple destinations but rarely are the e-mail servers clever enough to boundle them up when sending them out.

Comment: @Torxed this is an implementation detail. MTAs are not required to bundle outgoing mail (although my hunch is most modern MTA software _does_), but they are _required_ to accept mail addressed to multiple recipients.

Answer (score 0):

`SMTP.sendmail` expects [a *list* of recipients](http://docs.python.org/2/library/smtplib.html#smtplib.SMTP.sendmail), but you're passing a string with concatenated email addresses:

> `SMTP.sendmail(from_addr, to_addrs, msg[, mail_options, rcpt_options])`
>
> > Send mail. The required arguments are an RFC 822 from-address string, ***a list*** of RFC 822 to-address strings (a bare string will be treated as a list with 1 address), and a message string.

(emphasis added)

You should pass the same list you join with `COMMASPACE` directly to `SMTP.sendmail` instead of passing the concatenated flat string.